# Get revision number of a remote repository

Tags: svn, webdav, revision

On the local machine it is no problem to get the revision number of a subversion repository with `svnversion`. Now I want to get the revision number from my online repository (WebDAV with Apache2).

I tried this:

```
svnversion http://nick:password@www.myhost.de/svn/test`
```

In a browser it worked as usual (just to ensure there weren't typos or so), but `svnversion` said that the directory cannot be found. So I presume I was on the wrong track.

How can I get the revision number?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re57.html) is just for working copies, but one way to query your repository would be to use [svn info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) as follows:

```
svn info http://nick:password@www.myhost.de/svn | grep Revision
```

Answer (score 9):

On Linux, if you want just the revision number:

svn info http://nick:password@www.myhost.de/svn/test | grep '^Revision:' | awk '{print $2}'

Answer (score 7):

A handy AWK one-liner to get only the number portion:

```
svn info http://nick:password@www.myhost.de/svn | awk '/Revision:/ { print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
svn info http://nick:password@www.myhost.de/svn/test
```

should return information about the remote repository, including Revision

Answer (score 6):

On new version of svn (1.9) you can do:

```
svn info --show-item revision svn://...
18436
```

This should return only the revision number.

All the grep version will break if your locale is not english.

For previous version, you can try

```
svn info --xml | grep '<entry' -3 | awk -F '=' '/revision="/ { print $2 }' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

If you can have the xml2 package a better way is to do:

```
svn info --xml | xml2 | grep /info/entry/@revision | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

Comment: The grep and awk versions both miss the accent in Révision.