# using bash to get revision number from subversion

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a shell script in bash to deploy websites from an svn repository. When I deploy a website, I name the exported directory *website_name*-R*revision_number*. I'd like the bash script to automatically rename the exported directory, so it needs to learn the current revision number from the export directory. If I run

```
$> svn info http://svn-repository/trunk

Path: trunk
URL: http://svn-repository/mystery/trunk
Repository Root: http://svn-repository/mystery
Repository UUID: b809e6ab-5153-0410-a985-ac99030dffe6
Revision: 624
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: author
Last Changed Rev: 624
Last Changed Date: 2010-02-19 15:48:16 -0500 (Fri, 19 Feb 2010)
```

The number after the string `Revision:` is what I want. How do I get that into a bash variable? Do I do string parsing of the output from the `svn info` command?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html). This will output the revision number/range with minimal additional cruft

Comment: This only seems to work with local working copies. When I try with a remote URL (as in the original question), I get an error that says it doesn't exist. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623378/get-revision-number-of-a-remote-repository

Comment: it is server side, not client side

Answer (score 26):

```
REVISION=`svn info http://svn-repository/trunk |grep '^Revision:' | sed -e 's/^Revision: //'`
```

It's simple, if inelegant.

Comment: More succinctly put as:
REVISION=`svn info http://svn-repository/trunk | sed -ne 's/^Revision: //p'`

Comment: Yeah, I always forget about the -n option to sed.

Comment: This is useful for more than just the revision number; I just used it to grab the repository URL.

Comment: `REVISION=\`svn info http://svn-repository/trunk | sed -ne 's/^Revision: //p'\`` - You need to escape the literal backticks with a backspace.

Comment: Remeber to set output language before this command:
`LANG=C
LC_MESSAGES=C`

Answer (score 6):

Parsing the 'Revision' string is not portable across different locales.
Eg. with my locale it is like:

```
...
Wersja: 6583
Rodzaj obiektu: katalog
Zlecenie: normalne
Autor ostatniej zmiany: ...
Ostatnio zmieniona wersja: 6583
Data ostatniej zmiany: 2013-03-21 11:33:44 +0100 (czw)
...
```

You don't wanna parse that :)

So, the best approach is to use 'svnversion' as oefe suggested. This is the tool mentioned for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

just use one awk command. much simpler as well.

```
var=$(svn info http://svn-repository/trunk | awk '/^Revision:/{print $2}')
```

Comment: Using awk for a search in line... bazooka style

Answer (score 5):

Without using sed, grep or awk:

```
REVISION=`svn info --show-item=revision --no-newline`
```

Comment: REVISION=`svn info --show-item=revision --no-newline  -r HEAD` to get latest version on server

Comment: Note that this is a revision that you checked out. When you checkout head this might include versions from other branches. So this is not a revision for the path you checkout.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn info http://svn-repository/trunk | grep Revision | tr -d 'Revison: '
```

Spits out the revision
Use backticks in your shell script to execute this and assign the results to a variable:

```
REVISION=`svn info http://svn-repository/trunk | grep Revision | tr -d 'Revison: '`
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a dozen different ways to do this, but I'd go with something simple like:

```
revision="$(svn info http://svn-repository/trunk | grep "^Revision:" | cut -c 11-)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the head revision number

```
svn info -r 'HEAD' | grep Revision | egrep -o "[0-9]+"
```

egrep is extended grep.

Answer (score 0):

```
REVISION=$(svn info http://svn-repository/trunk |grep '^Revision:' | sed -e 's/^Revision: //p')
echo $REVISION
```