# SVN User Restricted to svn info

Tags: bash, svn, repository

I am writing a Bash script that checks several SVN directories to see if they are running the current version.  The `svn info /path/to/svn` works fine, since I am on the filesystem, but the `svn info http://svnserver/path/to/svn` requires a username/password, as suggested on [Get revision number of a remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623378/get-revision-number-of-a-remote-repository).  I don't want to embed my own password in the script for security reasons.  If I don't embed the password, though, and just type it in at the prompt, I can't capture it into the variable.

So if I have to use a username and password, can I add a user to my svn repository that is *only* able to get the output of SVN Info?  Or even just the revision?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it, but:

- If remote repository requires authentication and you provide it at least once (without `--no-auth-cache` option), these credentials will be stored and used next times for this *local user* in this *host*

Comment: I suspected as much.  Since this is a script that we regularly run on dozens of servers, though, just caching the credentials doesn't help me all that much.

If anyone else has suggestions, I'd love to hear them; otherwise I'll mark it as answered by LB.